# Real DOM is never updated while the state is mutated

Tags: reactjs, server-sent-events, react-dom

I am currently porting an old plain JS app to React. The old app received log messages/events on an SSE stream and appended them to the DOM. Everything was visible in real-time (live updates) and rendering was quite fast (if the logs are already there it took about 130ms to fetch and display 300 logs).

Doing the same thing in React seems to be tricky. I have used an `useEffect` hook to subscribe to the SSE stream and I am calling `setState` in the `onmessage` callback. Everything works (the SSE connection is successfully established once, is closed correctly and the output is correct), but it is really slow.

I do not get any output for 10 whole seconds, and then everything is displayed at once (no live updates). I already did some debugging. `setState()` calls are not batched in this context (which is fine I guess?) and are applied immediately. The components are also rendered immediately on every change (that's why it probably takes 10s instead of 100ms). But the strange thing is, even when the component is re-rendered all the time, the result is never displayed in the browser. As long as I am continuously getting events and updating the state, the rendered results seems to be discarded and the user sees no updates at all. Any tips how to solve this?

React Version:

```
17.0.1
```

Minimal Example:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
   
function App() {
    console.log('rendering...');
    const [state, setState] = useState<any[]>([]);
    useEffect(function() {
        let sse = new EventSource('/api/v1/events');
        sse.onmessage = (ev : MessageEvent) => {
            const item = JSON.parse(ev.data);
            if (item === null) {
                sse.close();
                return;
            }
            console.log('received', item.msg);
            setState((items) => ([...items, item]));
        };
        return () => {
            sse.close();
        };
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            { state.map((x, i) => (<div key={i}>{x.msg}</div>)) }
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Output:

```
received X
rendering...
received Y
rendering...
received Z
rendering...
x300 (but no visible change in the browser for 10 seconds)
```

Comment: Have you tried running the same code with React 16.x?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that `sse` doesn't persist for the full lifetime of the component.

To avoid this issue, you should use `useRef` hook.

`sse` will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

```js
    const sse = useRef<any>();

    useEffect(function() {
        sse.current = new EventSource('/api/v1/events');
        sse.current.onmessage = (ev : MessageEvent) => {
            const item = JSON.parse(ev.data);
            if (item === null) {
                sse.currernt.close();
                return;
            }
            console.log('received', item.msg);
            setState((items) => ([...items, item]));
        };
        return () => {
            sse.current.close();
        };
    }, []);
```